# Scraping Trustpilot Reviews input into Google Sheet using AppScripts - No data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape reviews from the Trustpilot website and input them into a Google Sheet.

I have used a Google Apps Script to do this, but I am running into issues where the script is executing without any errors, but the data isn't appearing in my Google Sheet.

Here is the script I am running (I have changed removed the name of company from TP link), what am I doing wrong?

```
function loadTrustPilotReviews() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("removed");
  var url = "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/removed";
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  // Extract user names
  var userNameRegex = /class="consumer-information__name">([^<]+)</g;
  var userNames = [];
  var match = userNameRegex.exec(content);
  while (match != null) {
    userNames.push(match[1]);
    match = userNameRegex.exec(content);
  }

  // Extract review texts
  var reviewTextRegex = /class="review-content__text">([^<]+)</g;
  var reviewTexts = [];
  match = reviewTextRegex.exec(content);
  while (match != null) {
    reviewTexts.push(match[1]);
    match = reviewTextRegex.exec(content);
  }

  // Extract review dates
  var reviewDateRegex = /class="review-content-header__dates--created">([^<]+)<\/span>/g;
  var reviewDates = [];
  match = reviewDateRegex.exec(content);
  while (match != null) {
    reviewDates.push(match[1]);
    match = reviewDateRegex.exec(content);
  }

  // Write data to sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1).setValue(userNames[i]);
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(reviewTexts[i]);
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(reviewDates[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The site that you are querying appear to create its data dynamically using javascript. You can check this for yourself by looking at the page source. In this case, you cannot scrape data from the site.